# How to create two layers with different criteria from a raster layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, spatial-analyst, raster-calculator, con

I have one raster layer I also turned into a slope layer. I need to create two rasters with different criteria ( first one needs specific slope and elevation, second needs just elevation) what tool would I use for this and how would I put it in the tool?

1 layer is elevation
I took that and made 1 slope layer

I need two rasters
Raster1: slope less than or equal to 5 and elevation less than 200
Raster2: elevation between 100 and 140

Comment: Are you using ArcGIS Pro or ArcMap to try to do this? Do you have a Spatial Analyst license?

Comment: Using Pro. Not sure what spatial analyst license is but o think so I have those tools. I tried using raster calculator and con but I am not sure if that’s right or if I’m typing in things wrong.

Comment: both con and calculator should work I think, though I think this is a specific Con-usecase. If you're unsure whether you type everythin in correctly: does the output make sense? Or does it throw an error?